# Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (5312x2988, max=4096x4096) - How do I resolve this issue?

Tags: android, bitmap

This is the tutorial I started with.

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/

Basically, I've uploaded an image and and I want to display it in a custom image viewer.

I've adjusted my php.ini like so to accept large uploads.

```
memory_limit = 128M
post_max_size = 1G 
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 1G
max_file_uploads = 20
```

This is the error I'm getting from the logcat

03-15 01:06:36.843: W/OpenGLRenderer(14403): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (5312x2988, max=4096x4096)

OK, so the problem is, when I try to display a picture that's 6M, 8M, 9M or 12MEGAPIXELS everything is fine. When I try display a 16Megapixels photo, it doesn't display.

Ok, but the image viewer in the tutorial displays the image. But I'm using a different class to display the images. Image viewer seems to display an image from you SdCard. FeedImageView allows you to display a picture saved on a server.

```
public class FeedImageView extends ImageView {

    public interface ResponseObserver {
        public void onError();

        public void onSuccess();
    }

    private ResponseObserver mObserver;

    public void setResponseObserver(ResponseObserver observer) {
        mObserver = observer;
    }

    /**
     * The URL of the network image to load
     */
    private String mUrl;

    /**
     * Resource ID of the image to be used as a placeholder until the network
     * image is loaded.
     */
    private int mDefaultImageId;

    /**
     * Resource ID of the image to be used if the network response fails.
     */
    private int mErrorImageId;

    /**
     * Local copy of the ImageLoader.
     */
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    /**
     * Current ImageContainer. (either in-flight or finished)
     */
    private ImageContainer mImageContainer;

    public FeedImageView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public FeedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public FeedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    /**
     * Sets URL of the image that should be loaded into this view. Note that
     * calling this will immediately either set the cached image (if available)
     * or the default image specified by
     * {@link VolleyImageView#setDefaultImageResId(int)} on the view.
     * 
     * NOTE: If applicable, {@link VolleyImageView#setDefaultImageResId(int)}
     * and {@link VolleyImageView#setErrorImageResId(int)} should be called
     * prior to calling this function.
     * 
     * @param url
     *            The URL that should be loaded into this ImageView.
     * @param imageLoader
     *            ImageLoader that will be used to make the request.
     */
    public void setImageUrl(String url, ImageLoader imageLoader) {
        mUrl = url;
        mImageLoader = imageLoader;
        // The URL has potentially changed. See if we need to load it.
        loadImageIfNecessary(false);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the default image resource ID to be used for this view until the
     * attempt to load it completes.
     */
    public void setDefaultImageResId(int defaultImage) {
        mDefaultImageId = defaultImage;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the error image resource ID to be used for this view in the event
     * that the image requested fails to load.
     */
    public void setErrorImageResId(int errorImage) {
        mErrorImageId = errorImage;
    }

    /**
     * Loads the image for the view if it isn't already loaded.
     * 
     * @param isInLayoutPass
     *            True if this was invoked from a layout pass, false otherwise.
     */
    private void loadImageIfNecessary(final boolean isInLayoutPass) {
        final int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        boolean isFullyWrapContent = getLayoutParams() != null
                && getLayoutParams().height == LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                && getLayoutParams().width == LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        // if the view's bounds aren't known yet, and this is not a
        // wrap-content/wrap-content
        // view, hold off on loading the image.
        if (width == 0 && height == 0 && !isFullyWrapContent) {
            return;
        }

        // if the URL to be loaded in this view is empty, cancel any old
        // requests and clear the
        // currently loaded image.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mUrl)) {
            if (mImageContainer != null) {
                mImageContainer.cancelRequest();
                mImageContainer = null;
            }
            setDefaultImageOrNull();
            return;
        }

        // if there was an old request in this view, check if it needs to be
        // canceled.
        if (mImageContainer != null && mImageContainer.getRequestUrl() != null) {
            if (mImageContainer.getRequestUrl().equals(mUrl)) {
                // if the request is from the same URL, return.
                return;
            } else {
                // if there is a pre-existing request, cancel it if it's
                // fetching a different URL.
                mImageContainer.cancelRequest();
                setDefaultImageOrNull();
            }
        }

        // The pre-existing content of this view didn't match the current URL.
        // Load the new image
        // from the network.
        ImageContainer newContainer = mImageLoader.get(mUrl,
                new ImageListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        if (mErrorImageId != 0) {
                            setImageResource(mErrorImageId);
                        }

                        if (mObserver != null) {
                            mObserver.onError();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(final ImageContainer response,
                            boolean isImmediate) {
                        // If this was an immediate response that was delivered
                        // inside of a layout
                        // pass do not set the image immediately as it will
                        // trigger a requestLayout
                        // inside of a layout. Instead, defer setting the image
                        // by posting back to
                        // the main thread.
                        if (isImmediate && isInLayoutPass) {
                            post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    onResponse(response, false);
                                }
                            });
                            return;
                        }

                        int bWidth = 0, bHeight = 0;
                        if (response.getBitmap() != null) {

                            setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
                            bWidth = response.getBitmap().getWidth();
                            bHeight = response.getBitmap().getHeight();
                            adjustImageAspect(bWidth, bHeight);

                        } else if (mDefaultImageId != 0) {
                            setImageResource(mDefaultImageId);
                        }

                        if (mObserver != null) {
                            mObserver.onSuccess();

                        }
                    }
                });

        // update the ImageContainer to be the new bitmap container.
        mImageContainer = newContainer;

    }

    private void setDefaultImageOrNull() {
        if (mDefaultImageId != 0) {
            setImageResource(mDefaultImageId);
        } else {
            setImageBitmap(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right,
            int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        loadImageIfNecessary(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        if (mImageContainer != null) {
            // If the view was bound to an image request, cancel it and clear
            // out the image from the view.
            mImageContainer.cancelRequest();
            setImageBitmap(null);
            // also clear out the container so we can reload the image if
            // necessary.
            mImageContainer = null;
        }
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {
        super.drawableStateChanged();
        invalidate();
    }

    /*
     * Adjusting imageview height
     */
    private void adjustImageAspect(int bWidth, int bHeight) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();

        if (bWidth == 0 || bHeight == 0)
            return;

        int swidth = getWidth();
        int new_height = 0;
        new_height = swidth * bHeight / bWidth;
        params.width = swidth;
        params.height = new_height;
        setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

How can I allow the picture to show with 16 megapixels in the FeedImageView class like the regular

```
private ImageView imgPreview;
```

class the tutorial uses?

Comment: I'd be wary of that site - some of the tutorials [have serious security vulnerabilities](http://awooga.jondh.me.uk/report/26). The code on offer here appears to do no authentication to check a file may be uploaded, and does not filter out non-image files, so arbitrary PHP code can be uploaded and executed.

Answer (score 7):

Set

`android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`

&

`android:largeHeap="true"`

within the application tag of the manifest file.

It seems like this will work fine for now. The animations are a tad bit choppy as I scroll the the pictures with these parameters set.

```xml
<application
    android:name="com.clxxxii.givenchy"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/givenchy"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
```

Comment: setting `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` does not works well with material design

Answer (score 0):

For displaying the image on image view, I prefer resizing the image and loading that image.

You can resize the image by referring the below mentioned link and this will also going to solve texture issue

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: i want to display the image in the feedlistview

Comment: feedlistliew takes a string and displays a picture saved on a server, image view takes a bitmap.

Comment: After the image is down load, you can optimize that image